# Focus DOM Element in React App in useEffect Problem

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, focus

I want to focus some html element when the component renders. I need that focus so that i am able to close the component on outside click. The problem is, when i inspect the actual focus with the developer tool, it stays on 'body' after the component got rendered.

So my idea was to explicit focus an element from that component, which doesnt work..

This is my code

```
// initiale the useRef
const initialFocusRef = useRef(null);

// connecting the ref to the div element
<div className="edi-frame" ref={initialFocusRef}>

// in useEffect i try to focus the element 
initialFocusRef.current.focus();
```

Ps. It works with an input field. But the component itself got no input field and when i insert one with type="hidden", it does not work anymore.

Can you guys help me to solve this issue? Thanks!

EDIT: I can only use Hooks / functional components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div` - is not a focusable element, but you can do it focusable by adding 
 attribute `tabindex`:

```
<div className="edi-frame" tabindex="-1" ref={initialFocusRef}>
```

If you want to close your component by clicking outside it, I suggest you to use [`react-onclickoutside`](https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside):

```
function ModalComponent({ close }) {
    const ref = useRef(null)
    useOnClickOutside(ref, close)
    return (
        <div className="edi-frame" ref={ref}>Some content</div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! that hint solved my problem, for future readers:
In React i had to implement it like this "tabIndex={-1}"